# What can cause Facebook to ignore Open Graph tags?

Tags: facebook

I have a Wordpress blog. I have tested three different ways (three plugins) that adds Open Graph tags to each my post. I have browsed source of my page many times. Everthing seems fine. Example:

```
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://blog.com/some-title/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Some Description" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2011-06-06T09:19:45+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2015-09-15T10:31:57+00:00" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="blog.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blog.com/files/2011/06/Rees.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1024" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="650" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://blog.com/files/2011/06/Rees.jpg?w=640" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

And... nothing. No matter, what I try to do, Facebook keeps displaying only title and description and there is no way I can force it to display image along with it.

Is there anything, I'm doing wrong or missing something?

**EDIT:** This is specific to a particular blog and to Facebook only. I can share the very same blog post on Twitter or Google+ and -- of course -- image appears. I can post a link from any other blog and it -- again -- works fine and appears on Facebook with proper image.

Comment: How long has it been since you added these tags? Facebook does not recrawl a page if it has not long been fetched.

Comment: I was trying to post an article written (posted to Wordpress) about an hour ago. Shouldn't Facebook try to crawl page / parse tags immediately, when user pastes its URL into status update box and when Facebook generates miniature, with title, text and photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an amazing tool... It's the Facebook "Debugger". It shows you how Facebook sees your page, including any errors it detects.

[Debugger - Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Comment: Though you haven't answered my question directly (what can cause), the tool you brought, which I didn't know, has just perfectly answered my question! :> Thus, I'm happy to accept your answer!

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without the debugger in my opinion. I'm lazy and use it every time I have an issue. Could you share what the problem was?

Comment: I, most certainly, will be using it every time, I'm stuck, starting from now. I haven't used it before asking, because I'm very new to Facebook and I wasn't aware of such tool. My problem was very obvious. I wasn't aware, that Facebook caches every link posted anywhere by anyone. I posted it once, when linked page had no featured image, then deleted post, then tried to re-post when linked page was already enriched with featured image and I was certain, that Facebook will use fresh "crawl" of page. It turned out, that it used cached version without image. Forcing cache refresh solved problem.